# Compiling an example script in .NET from an API emulator github project

Tags: c#, .net, bloomberg

I have a .NET [project](https://github.com/Robinson664/bemu) for emulating the Bloomberg API.

There are example .cs scripts to run in the "Examples" folder.

I understand I need to compile these first using csc by running in command prompt

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CSC.EXE IntradayBarDataRequest.cs
```

But this produces

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.4084.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

IntradayBarDataRequest.cs(17,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Bloomberglp' could not be found (are you
        missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
IntradayBarDataRequest.cs(106,45): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Event' could not be found (are you missing
        a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to add a file or something to the folder, so the compiler knows what to look for?

Comment: It's not clear how you acquired the package. You've tagged the post as _.NET_ but haven't specified a version.  The [Github project](https://github.com/Robinson664/bemu/blob/master/BEmu/BEmu_csh.csproj) shows _<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>_ which is _.NET Framework_ not _.NET_. There also seems to be a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bemu#supportedframeworks-body-tab) for _.NET Core 3.0_.  You may consider reading about [.Net Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0).

Comment: You need to reference use MSBuild.exe to compile the project

Comment: To get the package, I basically just downloaded the zip file. How do I get this emulator working? Is there some basic set of steps for .NET framework software from github?